# How exactly have T5 3B and 11B models been scaled?

Tags: transformer

I've been trying to understand the difference between the large T5 model, and the 3B model. I thought it was a typo in a paper referencing it, but the original paper says the same thing. (For reference, I'm quoting from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10683.pdf#page=36)

Base uses `dmodel` of 768, 12 heads and `dkv` of 64. `12 x 64 = 768`, all good. 12 layers in each of encoder and decoder. `dff` is 3072, which means the FFN, in PyTorch terms would be:

```
x = nn.Linear(768, 768 * 4)
x = F.relu(x)
x = nn.Linear(768 * 4, 768)
```

We then have Large size, which increases the model dimension, `dmodel`, to 1024, with 16 heads each of `dkv=64`, `16 x 64 = 1024`; it keeps the same x4 ratio for the FFN, so it is `1024 -> 4096 -> 1024`. It uses 24 layers in each of encoder and decoder, and has 770M params, compared to the base model 220M params.

> 3B and 11B... we use `dmodel` = 1024, a 24 layer encoder and decoder, and `dkv` = 128. For the “3B” variant, we use `dff` = 16,384 with 32-headed attention

Maybe it is just sloppy language, but I took 32-headed attention to mean there are 32 heads? But that is twice as many heads and twice the `dkv`, `32 x 128 = 4096` which is not equal to the `dmodel` of 1024. Though 4096 would then make sense, as then the standard `4x` in the FFN would match the `dff` they give us: `4096 -> 16384 -> 4096`.

However, I believe that would be a lot more than 3B parameters then? So did they mean to write "with head dimension of 32" ? And then their FFN is doing a fairly novel 16x ratio: `1024 -> 16384 -> 1024`.

The paper goes on to say:

> for “11B” we use `dff` = 65,536 with 128-headed attention...

So does this mean their model dimension of 1024 is divided into 128 heads each of dimension `dkv` = 8? And then their FFN is `1024 -> 65536 -> 1024`?

If this is true, does anyone have any insight, papers, references to experiments, etc. on why if they were sticking with a model dimension of 1024, they didn't just stick with 16 heads of `dkv`=64?

By the way, not increasing model dimension as scaling up is unusual (e.g. GPT-3, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14165.pdf#page=8, keeps increasing it, and keeps head-dim almost the same; they also always use `dff = dmodel x 4`), so I've been surprised the paper doesn't draw more attention to it, only saying it is efficient on a TPU. The various blogs and articles about T5 that I've found don't seem to mention it at all.